# Relationship between colour temperature and actual temperature?

Tags: color

Is there a formula for getting the actual temperature from the colour temperature?

Comment: The actual temperature of *what*?

Comment: @PhilipKendall I think that is partly what the OP wants to know. Also, in this case it is not particularly relevant due to where colour temperature comes from.

Comment: This is a physics question, not a photog question.

Comment: I think that this is a question which won't be accurately answered in other SE sites because of specific colorimetric aspect involved (see my answer) even if it is not exactly on topic here.

Comment: @EuriPinhollow Physics and/or Optical Engineering handles colorimetry quite well. That's completely separate from figuring out how to adjust a photograph to produce an apparent color temperature or balance in the final image.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the calculation of black body temperature is not relevant to still photography. This is better suited at Physics.SE.

Answer (score 3):

From what I know there is not a formula.

The colour temperature is defined as the temperature of an ideal black body that radiates light of that colour.  Unfortunately most objects are not ideal black body radiators so there is no direct comparison.

For example, LED lights do not emit light by thermal radiation, as such the colour of the light is not determined by the temperature.

Some objects such as incandescent lamp approximates a black body and emits light in thermal so you can approximate their temperature to their colour temperature.

Colour temperature can seem counter intuitive to start as the higher the colour temperature the "colder(bluer)" the scene, and "warm" scenes have a lower colour temperature.

andy

Comment: Exactly correct.  You must be a physicist or something :-) .  I might add that even incandescents deviate from the Black-body curve because of the coatings on the inside of the bulb. These coatings have spectral transmission curves which adjust the apparent color.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to tell because there is lot of temperature and colours definitions.

If we want to align colour of the black body (note that black body is defined as ideal body that absorbs and emits photons only; there is no reflection from the surface and no transmission through the volume.) and its temperature there is [Planck's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck's_law) which, by the way, caused revolution in physics. It describes wavelength distribution of the black body with given temperature.

If we want to align colour of grey body (there can be reflections; it absorbs lower ammount of light and emits lower intensities) one can use Planck's law and multiply the result by [emissivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emissivity). In reality one needs to know spectral emissivity of the body and spectral transmisivity of the ambient space (glass, air, dust, filters,...). Really hot bodies can be considered grey bodies.

*But there are plenty of colourful things that are colourful, yet cold.*

Such things, for example leaves, reflects only part of the (visible) spectra and the rest is absorbed. What you can see is the reflected light. [Chlorophyll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorophyll) inside the cell reflects mostly in green region, in the rest of the visible spectra it absorbs the light more.

*And what about light sources?*

For lightbulbs we can use Planck's law with corrections on the glass transmissivity. For halogen lights we may use corrections to the gas spectra. In case of [Xenon(TM) headlamps, neon tubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas-discharge_lamp#Color), [sodium lights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium-vapor_lamp) there is no physical connection between temperature and colour (=spectrum) of the light. The colour of the light is determined by (in)ability of the excited particles to emit photon of given energy (= wavelength = colour).

In case of [fluorescent lamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorescent_lamp#Phosphor_composition) the colour is determined by the spectrum emitted by gas filling the tube and by emission spectrum of the phosphors that absorb invisible UV light and emit light in visible region.

Spectrum, and colour, of [LED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode#Colors_and_materials)s is determined by [band gap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_gap) of the P-N junction in the diode. Colour of the [LASER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser) is determined by the energy of metastable states in the gain medium.

*What about colourful fireworks?*

There are [chemicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fireworks#Pyrotechnic_compounds) added to the compound. The chemical bonds there absorbs part of the spectra and form colour filter.

In al cases above, the "temperature of the light" may be estimated by comparison the overall colour of hte light with the colour of the light from black body on given temperature. Light from LED diode with temperature of, say, 9600 K will be simillar to the light of tugsten fillament heated to 9326 °C.

There are also "cold colours" and "warm colours" that have [Heath Robinsonian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._Heath_Robinson) connection between colour and temperature:
Sky is usually blue (because blue light [refracts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_(optics)) with sharper angles than red light) and blue sky is usually reflected by cold water. Hence blue colour, with purple and green, is considered cold. Flame and glowing iron are hot, right?, hence red, orange and yellow are considered warm.

**tl;dr** Colour temperature is the temperature of hypothetical black body which will illuminate the scene simillar to the light source.

---

Side note: Do not touch anything glowing blue. Even if blue colour is considered cold, the glowing thing dosn't know that and is really, really hot.

Comment: ORLY?  a blue LED is hot?  You are also forgetting bioluminescent effects.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft You are free to edit. And you probably know, that neither of blue LED neither blue fluorescent tube was in my mind...

Comment: A LED is not glowing, it's shining.

Answer (score -2):

There is no direct relation between colour temperature and temperature as an object is not guaranteed to emit the light itself: any white object which diffuses the light of another object will have same colour temperature but obviously won't have the same temperature because it only looks similar.

Other than that: yes, there is a direct **correlation** between the colour temperature of an object known to be not illuminated externally and it's temperature, this is why colour temperature is named temperature in the first place. The colour temperature will **roughly** be it's temperature. However, there are at least two uncertain factors which contribute to the recorded colour temperature uncertainity:

- inaccurately specified colour response of cameras which will never be sufficient for scientific purposes unless each camera is studied. Known camera data from different programs is optimised for different tasks and this makes recorded colour temperature less exact
- spectral emission of a **black body** is well known but most materials are not black, they will absorb part of own emission altering visible colour
- there are two kinds of colour temperature: black body correlated and daylight correlated. Imaging programs are commonly using the daylight correlation for camera characterisation and you will need specialised software and study your camera spectral response to learn the black body correlated temperature. This happens because D65 and 6500K black body have different spectrums and are thus recorded differently because cameras are not standard observers i.e. are not matching Luther-Ives criterion

Comment: A different nitpick (and I freely admit, this is being very pedantic), but astronomically speaking, you have to account for relative velocity between camera and object (i.e., redshift/blueshift). Just calling an object "6000K", without knowing if it's approaching or receding, can yield a wide range of _actual_ temperatures. You'd have to look at emission spectra, and determine the degree of redshift/blueshift, and adjust the measured color temperature. After doing that, you have the actual temperature.

Comment: @scottbb I cannot see a point in your first comment. Black body emitting light recorded as D65 by camera won't have temperature of 6500K, that is what I am talking about. I understand that D65 is same CIEXYZ point as black body 6500K but cameras are not CIEXYZ, they are not colorimeters. Additionally I added it after the Carl's comment.

Comment: Ah, ok. I understand what you're talking about now.

Answer (score -3):

As objects are heated they reach a temperature where they begin to glow. First dull-red-hot, then cherry-red, then white-hot. Seems the temperature and color outputted are the same regardless of material. For centuries, iron workers, glass blowers and ceramic potters, have used the glowing color as a marker. The Celsius temperature scale is favored by scientist because is blends in with the metric system.

Their seems to be no limit as to how high a temperature is possible however the lower limit is -273.16°C. It is presumed that if a material is cooled to this absolute lowest possible temperature, modular motion ceases. The Absolute temperature scales sets -273.16°C as the zero point. Thus all readings will be positive, no confusing negative temperatures with positive. The Absolute scale was renamed the Kelvin scale to honor William Thomas, 1st Baron Kelvin.

K = C + 273.16

C = K – 273.16

400°C --- 673°K Red heat, visible in the dark

474°C --- 747°K -- Red heat, visible in the twilight

525°C --- 798°K -- Red heat, visible in the daylight

581°C --- 854°K - Red heat, visible in the sunlight

700°C ---973°K - Dark red

800°C --- 1073°K - Dull cherry-red

900°C --- 1173°K - Cherry-red

1000°C -- 1273°K - Bright cherry-red

1100°C --- 1373°K - Orange-red

Standard Candle 1930°K

Incandescent carbon electric standard candle 2080°K

Incandescent tungsten electric standard candle 2400°K

Sunlight mean noon 5400°K

Photographic daylight 5500°K

500 watt photo-flood tungsten 3400°K

500 watt photographic studio flood 3200°K

100 watt general service tungsten bulb 2900°K
 [image]

Comment: Is there an answer here?